# iOS Core Data change a few properties on object takes too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios8

I have my Core Data object which has some properties like:

```
@interface ModuleCD : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * locationTimestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * moduleId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * status;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *openPositions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *slaves;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *tracks;

@end
```

The problem is that I have many and many objects in openPositions and tracks. There are thousands positions saved and each track could have many positions too. My problem is that when I update "simple" values of ModuleCD (first six values, but mainly only timestamp is changed) it takes too long. It looks like it's recreating openPositions and tracks and so but there wasn't changes in there. So where could be problem? I am using 3 layer Core Data model (private temp context, main UI context and writer private contenxt which has set persistent store). It blocks UI for several seconds and it just changes timestamp.

**Edit:**
My update method (I update it from another similar object which is not related to core data):

```
@implementation ModuleCD (Ext)

- (void)updateValues:(Module *)module
{
...
self.locationTimestamp = module.locationTimestamp;
...
}
```

My save context methods:

```
- (void)saveTempContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context withCompletion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    if (!error) {
        [self saveMainContextCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
            completion(error);
        }];
    } else {
        completion(error);
    }
}

- (void)saveMainContextCompletion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
            [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if(!error){
                //Write to disk after saving on the main UI context
                [self saveWriterContextCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
                    completion(error);
                }];
            } else {
                completion(error);
            }
        } else {
            completion(nil);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)saveWriterContextCompletion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {

    [self.writerManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.writerManagedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"CORE DATA MASTER CONTEXT ERROR : %@", error);
            completion(error);
        } else {
            completion(nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

I update context everytime when user uses pull-to-refresh on tableView and I get response from server.

```
- (void)updateModulesWithModules:(NSArray *)newModules completion:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion
{
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[CoreDataManager manager] managedObjectContext];
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    temporaryContext.parentContext = managedObjectContext;

    [temporaryContext performBlock:^{

        NSArray *modules = [[CoreDataManager manager]fetchArrayWithoutSubentitiesWithName:@"ModuleCD" andPredicate:nil inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];

///
...
here some changes, calling updateValues method 
...
///

        [[CoreDataManager manager] saveTempContext:temporaryContext withCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
            completion(error);
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: How do you change the properties? How often do you save the context? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: I updated my question with more code from my app. Hope it helps.